# How to make a class template's member function's argument dependent on the class template parameter value?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, compile-time

How can one choose a class template member function's argument type depending on the class template parameter value?

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
template <class T, bool plainPointer=true>
class C
{
    // pseudocode below
    void f(plainPointer ? T * x : std::shared_ptr<T> x) { /*implementation*/ }
};
```

That is, if `plainPointer==true`, the following class member function should be defined:

```cpp
void f(T * x) { /*implementation*/ }
```

otherwise, this member function should be defined:

```cpp
void f(std::shared_ptr<T> x) { /*implementation*/ }
```

I would like to have a *single implementation for both functions*, and only the argument type of `f` should be `plainPointer` dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to make the choice between 2 types:

```
void f(std::conditional_t<plainPointer, T*, std::shared_ptr<T>> x) {
   /*implementation*/ 
}
```

Note that for this approach to work, both options inside the `conditional_t` must be well-formed for all instantiations.

---

If you plan on using that function argument type multiple times in the class, you can create a type alias that you can reuse:

```
using ptr_type = std::conditional_t<plainPointer, T*, std::shared_ptr<T>>;
```